# mkisofs can't find file

Tags: iso, burning, mkisofs

I'm trying to create a .iso file using `mkisofs`.

I have the following folders:

```
my OS
|
|--src
|--bin
```

I used the following command:

```
mkisofs -R -input-charset utf8 -b bin/boot.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -o os.iso bin
```

the command was run from the parent directory (my OS) and I got the following error:

```
genisoimage: Uh oh, I can't find the boot image 'bin/boot.bin' !
```

I checked, and the file `bin/boot.bin` does exists. I tried writing `./` before the directory, and using real paths, but no good.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Could you give us the file permissions of bin/boot.bin?

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo the permissions are: -rw-r--r-- (I'm the owner of the file)

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo it's not a permission problem - I run it on root user and got the same result.

Comment: There were some non-printing control characters in your command that were making it appear strangely on my browser. I have edited it to fix this, please confirm that the command is correct.

Comment: @Random832 the command is correct, thnx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are creating an image of the `bin` directory, either put your boot image in `bin/bin/boot.bin` or specify it as `boot.bin`. The boot image path is relative to the source path (`bin`).

Comment: I'm not creating a image of the hull directory, just the file thats in the `bin` directory. the file is called `boot.bin`. any way, I trued full paths (`/home/<user>` etc) and it didn't help, so it's not a directory problem.

Comment: @elyashiv You are creating an image of the `bin` directory: `mkisofs ... bin`. Your boot image path is relative to that directory. If it is right there in `bin`, you just say `-b boot.bin`. Do you get it?